# How to use a Ruby block to assign variables in chef recipe

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to execute Ruby logic on the fly in a Chef recipe and believe that the best way to achieve this is with a block.

I am having difficulty transferring variables assigned inside the block to the main code of the chef recipe. This is what I tried:

```
ruby_block "Create list" do
  block do
    to_use ||= []
    node['hosts'].each do |host|
      system( "#{path}/command --all" \
              " | awk '{print $2; print $3}'" \
              " | grep #{host} > /dev/null" )
      unless $? == 0
        to_use << host
      end
    end
    node['hosts'] = to_use.join(',')
  end
  action :create
end

execute "Enable on hosts" do
  command "#{path}/command --enable -N #{node['hosts']}"
end
```

Rather than try to re-assign the chef attribute on the fly, I also tried to create new variables in the block but still can't find a way to access them in the `execute` statement.

I was originally using a  class and calling methods however it was compiled before the recipe and I really need the logic to be executed at runtime, during the recipe.

Comment: The best chef receipes are idpotent, so executing ruby logic on the fly is not generally a good idea. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: `node['hosts'].select!` would modify it inplace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is [compile time versus converge time](http://docs.chef.io/chef_client.html#the-chef-client-title-run). Your block will be run at converge time but at this time the `node['host']` in the execute resource has already been evaluated.

The best solution in this case would be to use [lazy evaluation](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#lazy-attribute-evaluation) so the variable will be expanded when the resource is converged instead of when it is compiled:

```
execute "Enable on hosts" do
  command lazy { "#{path}/command --enable -N #{node['hosts']}" }
end
```

Here's a little warning though, the lazy operator has to include the full `command` attribute text and not only the variable, it can work only as first keyword after the attribute name.