# Removing packages in Chef, from a generated list

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to generate a list of packages during the chef run and remove them.

I've tried to use a ruby block to set a `run_state` variable. The variable ends up being empty. I also tried adding lazy evaluation in `package` based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30424244/how-to-use-a-ruby-block-to-assign-variables-in-chef-recipe) but it resulted in compile errors. I have also looked into placing the list in a file but the docs say support for using file names for package is not available.

Is there a reasonable way to remove a list of packages from a converge time variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
ruby_block "somehow get the list of packages to remove" do
  block do
    node.run_state['remove_packages'] = %w( foo bar baz )
  end
end

package "remove the list of packages" do
  package_name lazy { node.run_state['remove_packages'] }
  action :remove
  only_if { node.run_state['remove_packages'] }
end
```

(tested with `chef-apply` 13.5.3)

Comment: I fixed the answer to use run_state instead of a node attribute. You should almost never write to node attributes for scratch space like this.

Comment: True, if you don't want to store the value on the chef-server.